# Hiding text and use Radio button to view it

Tags: html, xhtml

I am trying to have some content show/appear if a certain radio button (YES) is selected. I have provided the text I have in HTML form. I believe this should be a very simple code but I am VERY rusty on my HTML. This is all within a table. If the YES radio is chosen, I would like the 3 Quantity portions to appears but if not then I would like them hidden. I hope this helps...

```
<tbody>
<td class="style1" colspan="2">
    <strong>Room Setup<br>
        <tr>
            <span class="style2"><em>Complete where applicable</em></span>
    </strong>
</td>
<td style="width: 255px;">
    *Is a Room Setup Required?
</td>
<td style="width: 202px;">
    <input name="roomsetup" value="yes" type="radio">
    Yes<br>
    <input name="roomsetup" value="no" type="radio">&nbsp; No
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 255px; height: 14px;">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 202px; height: 14px;">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 255px;" class="style3">
        Quantity&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td style="width: 202px;">
        <input name="roomchairs" value="yes" type="checkbox">&nbsp; Chairs Needed<br>
        <input name="roomchairsquantity" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 255px;">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td style="width: 202px;">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 255px;" class="style3">
        Quantity&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td style="width: 202px;">
        <input name="checktables" value="yes" type="checkbox">&nbsp; Tables Needed<br>
        <input name="roomquantitytable" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 255px;">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td style="width: 202px;">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 255px;" class="style3">
        Quantity&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td style="width: 202px;">
        <input name="checktableclothes" value="yes" type="checkbox">&nbsp; Tableclothes
        Needed<br>
        <input name="roomquantitycloth" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 255px;" class="style3">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td style="width: 202px;">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are about two ways you can do this.

(1) Using PHP

```
<?php 

if($_POST["RADIOBOX NAME"] =="OPTION YOU WANT TO SELECT") {
echo "WHAT YOU WANT TO SAY";
//USE THE ECHO AS MUCH AS NEEDED
}
?>
```

(2) I think that there is a JavaScript for this, however, I am not familiar with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some javascript for that. If you can use something like jQuery, this is really easy to do, and it's easy to find brazillions tutorial on Internet.

For exemple [this one](http://iamzed.com/2006/12/14/using-jquery-to-show-hide-form-elements-based-on-a-checkbox-selection/) or [this one](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/basic-show-and-hide)